# How do I convert a MKV file to H.264/AVC with a resolution of 640x360 using FFMPEG?

Tags: video, conversion, ffmpeg

I have a MKV video which I want to put in my mobile (a Nokia XM 5800) and based on [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/5800_XpressMusic) I can play H.264/AVC format videos on it. Based on what [I have read](http://forum.dailymobile.se/index.php/topic,9857.0.html), the container should be MP4 and I can encode it using XVID codec. The problem is I don't know how.

Since I am using Linux (Arch), I was wondering if I can achieve this using FFMPEG. If so, please enlighten me on how to do this. I want the video to use the native screen size of the device, 640x360, with a reasonably good video and audio quality.

If you can also suggest other tools that will make it easier, please suggest.

I also prefer command line tools over GUI ones.

Answer (score 4):

[Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) has a useful GUI interface that will let you resize and transcode.
`mencoder` (part of [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/)) can do it too, but it's also command line.

I think the `ffmpeg` line you want is something like this:

```
ffmpeg -s 640x360 -i in.mkv -vcodec libx264 -o new.mp4
```

- `-s` sets the output size
- `-i` is input file
- `-vcodec` sets the output codec (see `ffmpeg -codecs` for your full list)
- `-o` sets the output filename (see `ffmpeg -formats` for your full list)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. I forgot to mention that I prefer command line tools over GUI ones [question updated].

Answer (score 1):

Splitting without re-encoding:

```
ffmpeg -ss [start-time] -t [length-time] -i [in-file-path] \
       -vcodec copy -acodec copy [out-file-path]
```

Example:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.00 -t 00:10:00.00 -i "/some/path/to/file.mp4" \
       -vcodec copy -acodec copy "/some/path/to/new file.mp4"
```